# Azure Notification Hubs with .NetCore 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

we have recently migrated to .NetCore 2.0 and so far I can say it went quite smoothly. However it seems that today we have stumbled upon the first hurdle. NotificationHubClient seems to require .NetFramework 4.5. We've tried installing NotificationHubClient nuget package but have been getting a series of exceptions, the latest was the missing library Systems.Diagnostics.Eventlog.

Is there a plan to release a fully .NetCore 2.0 compatible version of Azure NotificationHubClient? #azure-notificationhubs

Answer (score 1):

We've been working on supporting .netcore for Notification Hubs, and this should be available in the next few weeks.

Thank you,

Karl

Comment: Any links available